# Will JPA eagerly fetch non-entity attributes?

Tags: jpa

I want to know if attributes such as `Int` or `Varchar2` are fetched eagerly or lazily when creating a regular query.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")
public class Room implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "room_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "number") 
    private String number;     

    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private Integer capacity;     //Will this be fetched eagerly???

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
    private Building building;

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Basically:

```
Room room = getRoomById(5); // select room from Room room where room.id = 5;
Integer roomCap = room.getCapacity(); //Will this create another query?
```

Or will it be inside the `room` object already?

Comment: what does the annotation `@Basic` say ? because that is what represents those types, and JPA bases things on the Java type, not some DB type. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/annotations.html#Basic

Comment: With Int and Varchar I meant the would be Integer and String in Java. Plain attributes, non-entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetching strategies eager or lazy apply to relationships or associated entities where you want to load the data from another table and not to the columns that are part of the same entity or table. Columns or fields that belong to the same entity or table are fetched when you retrieve the entity and no separate query is fired.

Comment: Does this apply to Hibernate and EclipseLink? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does. It applies to all JPA implementations.

Answer (score 0):

when use lazy loading after data call on db after that you want to this object inside object your query go to db and execute db.

When you eager attribute get All element thats object